# Django accessing context data inside get_success_url

Tags: django, django-views

In my get_context_data method I create context variable only if certain conditions are met.

I want my form to be able to redirect different urls regarding that context variable is created or not.

How to access context['something'] in get_success_url method? Or is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_context_data` won't even be called if the form is valid, because a redirect needs no context. You should put that calculation somewhere else, perhaps into a separate method which could be called both from `get_context_data` and `form_valid`.

Comment: In my case redirect is not based on form validation but on other process which return or doesn't  return certain data. Namely Celery task.

Comment: Well, `get_success_url` only exists in form views and is only called from `form_valid`. But the point is the same; you don't need template context when you're redirecting, so the calculation of this value should be independent of that.

Comment: I agree with you now!